# How to sort series by episode IDs in the example xml

Tags: python, elementtree

How can I sort the series in the below xml based on the episode Ids?

```xml
<response>
  <movies_added/>
  <movies_removed/>
  <series_added>
    <series_meta_data>
      <displayName>Game of Thrones</displayName>
      <seriesItems>
        <seriesItem>
          <episodeName>Lord Snow</episodeName>
          <episodeID>S01E03</episodeID>
        </seriesItem>
        <seriesItem>
          <episodeName>Winter Is Coming</episodeName>
          <episodeID>S01E01</episodeID>
        </seriesItem>
        <seriesItem>
          <episodeName>The Kingsroad</episodeName>
          <episodeID>S01E02</episodeID>
        </seriesItem>
      </seriesItems>
    </series_meta_data>
    <series_meta_data>
      <displayName>Breaking Bad</displayName>
      <seriesItems>
        <seriesItem>
          <episodeName>Cat's in the Bag...</episodeName>
          <episodeID>S01E02</episodeID>
        </seriesItem>
        <seriesItem>
          <episodeName>...And the Bag's in the River</episodeName>
          <episodeID>S01E03</episodeID>
        </seriesItem>
        <seriesItem>
          <episodeName>Pilot</episodeName>
          <episodeID>S01E01</episodeID>
        </seriesItem>
      </seriesItems>
    </series_meta_data>
  </series_added>
  <series_removed/>
</response>
```

the expected output should be like this:

```xml
<response>
  <movies_added/>
  <movies_removed/>
  <series_added>
    <series_meta_data>
      <displayName>Game of Thrones</displayName>
      <seriesItems>
        <seriesItem>
          <episodeName>Winter Is Coming</episodeName>
          <episodeID>S01E01</episodeID>
        </seriesItem>
        <seriesItem>
          <episodeName>The Kingsroad</episodeName>
          <episodeID>S01E02</episodeID>
        </seriesItem>
        <seriesItem>
          <episodeName>Lord Snow</episodeName>
          <episodeID>S01E03</episodeID>
        </seriesItem>
      </seriesItems>
    </series_meta_data>
    <series_meta_data>
      <displayName>Breaking Bad</displayName>
      <seriesItems>
        <seriesItem>
          <episodeName>Pilot</episodeName>
          <episodeID>S01E01</episodeID>
        </seriesItem>
        <seriesItem>
          <episodeName>Cat's in the Bag...</episodeName>
          <episodeID>S01E02</episodeID>
        </seriesItem>
        <seriesItem>
          <episodeName>...And the Bag's in the River</episodeName>
          <episodeID>S01E03</episodeID>
        </seriesItem>
      </seriesItems>
    </series_meta_data>
  </series_added>
  <series_removed/>
</response>
```

EDIT: This what I tried so far:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def get_episode_id(series_container):
    series_container.find("episodeID").text


tree = ET.parse("question.xml")

series_containers = tree.findall(".//series_meta_data/seriesItems")
print(series_containers)

for series_container in series_containers:
    series_container[:] = sorted(series_container, key=get_episode_id(series_container))

tree.write("new.xml")
```

and getting:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Have you tried anything, can you add a sample code that you have tried?

Comment: Updated what I have tried so far in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. The function used as key when sorting needs to return the attribute to compare on. Also you need to call the key on elements of the iterable, not the iterable itself. Fixing these issues seems to result in working code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def get_episode_id(series_container):
    return series_container.find("episodeID").text


tree = ET.parse("question.xml")

series_containers = tree.findall(".//series_meta_data/seriesItems")

for series_container in series_containers:
    series_container[:] = sorted(series_container, key=get_episode_id)

tree.write("new.xml")
```

Comment: Yes, that worked!